# Call Custom API to send email notification from Prometheus Alertmanager

Tags: mongodb, alert, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have set an alert rule in Prometheus for MongoDB metrics. Now want send an email notification, for that I want configure Alertmanager. I can not access SMTP server directly as per our project process. For that we have a custom developed API that I can only call.

Now I am little confused how I can call a custom API from alert manager configuration file (alertmanager.yml), in documentation it has been given how to give SMTP details.

Can anyone help to understand how I can call custom API for email notification.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I created a web hook for alertmanager here is the config i used in alertmanager:

```
receivers:
- name: 'general'
  webhook_config:
  - url: https://my-webhook:8080/
    send_resolved: true
```

[Here](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#webhook_config) is the doc on webhook (not a lot there) 
Also [here](https://github.com/alerta/prometheus-config) i found example how to configure it.

Good luck.